# How do I call functions on objects initialized by jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a plugin has been initialized on a object, as in this example; `$('.selector').somePlugin()`.

The plugin function someFunction defined as:

```
    function Plugin(e) {
      ...
    }
    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
      someFunction: function() {
        ...
      }
    }

    $.fn.Plugin = function(){
      return this.each(function(){
        if(!$.data(this, 'plugin')){
          $.data(this, 'plugin', new Plugin(this));
        }
      });
    });
```

Is it possible to run "someFunction" by doing something like `$('.selector').someFunction()`?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: If I understand what you ask correctly it's probably gonna be $('.selector').somePlugin().someFunction().

Comment: This depends entirely on how the plugin has been written. Could you please show us more of the plugins code, or tell us which one it is so we can look up the source.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well the plugin I'm currently facing the challenge with is Fotorama http://fotorama.io/, I'm trying to call the requestFullScreen(). Allthough I was wondering if there was a general way to do it that was some sort of best practice.

Comment: @gforce301 yes, I've tried multiple variations including mrdeadsvens suggestion, which mostly returns someFunction is not a function

Answer (score 0):

There is API documentation for Fotorama, the plugin you are using. It is found here: [API](http://fotorama.io/customize/api/) There is an example there:

```
$(function () {
    // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
    var $fotoramaDiv = $('#fotorama').fotorama();

    // 2. Get the API object.
    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

    // 3. Inspect it in console.
    console.log(fotorama);
});
```

And a list of methods. One of which is:

> fotorama.requestFullScreen()
>   Opens fotorama in fullscreen mode, if allowed in options.

I would suggest following the instructions found in that API.

Comment: thank you for you response. Yes, I am aware that the API documentation suggests that you can call it like that. But this requires manual initialization on each specific gallery. Meaning I would have to create dynamic variable names, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Well how many galleries could you possibly have that manually initializing the plugin is such a hassle? I look at it like an automobile. You get automatic or you get manual but you can't drive it in both modes at the same time. I guess you have to decide how important manually calling `requestFullScreen` is to you.